404 error with insomnia any help greatly appreciated
We are reviving a 404 error with http://127.0.0.1:5000/chat we access "hello world" from http://127.0.0.1:5000 our web browser.  We seem to have tried everything, any insight would be greatly appreciated, thx
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, send_from_directory, Response
from flask_cors import CORS
import openai
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from typing import Union
from openai import OpenAIError, RateLimitError
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

# Load environment variables from .env file
load_dotenv()

# Get the OpenAI API key from the environment variable
openai.api_key = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')

# Initialize Flask app
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

# Explicitly setting debug and environment
app.config['ENV'] = 'development'
app.config['DEBUG'] = True

# Set up the database configuration
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = (
    'mysql+mysqlconnector://osric_user:Temporal1!@localhost/osric_db'
)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

# Initialize the database and migration modules
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

# Define campaign state
campaign_state = {
    "characters": [],
    "sessions": []
}

# Generate response using OpenAI API
def generate_response(input_text: str) -> str:
    prompt = f"OSRIC campaign response: {input_text}"
    try:
        response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
            messages=[
                {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."},
                {"role": "user", "content": prompt}
            ],
            max_tokens=150
        )
        return response['choices'][0]['message']['content'].strip()
    except OpenAIError as e:
        return f"Error occurred: {str(e)}"
    except RateLimitError:
        return "Rate limit error: You have exceeded your quota."
    except Exception as e:
        return f"An error occurred: {str(e)}"

# Flask route for chat endpoint
@app.route('/chat', methods=['POST'])
def chat() -> Union[Response, tuple[Response, int]]:
    if request.json is None:
        app.logger.error("Invalid input: request.json is None")
        return jsonify({"error": "Invalid input"}), 400

    user_input: str = request.json.get('input')
    if not user_input or not isinstance(user_input, str):
        app.logger.error(f"Invalid input: {user_input}")
        return jsonify({"error": "Invalid input"}), 400

    try:
        response_text: str = generate_response(input_text=user_input)
        return jsonify({"response": response_text})
    except Exception as e:
        app.logger.error(f"Error processing request: {e}")
        return jsonify(
            {"error": "An error occurred while processing the request"}
        ), 500

# Flask route for adding a character
@app.route('/add_character', methods=['POST'])
def add_character():
    if request.json is None:
        return jsonify({"error": "Invalid character data"}), 400

    character = request.json.get('character')
    if not character:
        return jsonify({"error": "Invalid character data"}), 400

    campaign_state["characters"].append(character)
    return jsonify({"message": "Character added", "character": character})

# Flask route for getting characters
@app.route('/get_characters', methods=['GET'])
def get_characters() -> Response:
    return jsonify({"characters": campaign_state["characters"]})

# Serve the index.html file
@app.route('/')
def serve_index() -> Response:
    return send_from_directory(directory='.', path='index.html')

# Serve the favicon.ico file
@app.route('/favicon.ico')
def favicon() -> Response:
    return send_from_directory(
        directory=os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'),
        path='favicon.ico'
    )

# Additional route to display a simple message
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return "Hello World"

# Main entry point
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host="127.0.0.1", port=5000)



we set our firewall rules to port 5000 we tried rewriting the code, but we still are not connecting

If your browser goes to Home on port 5000 do you still see 404?
